# Lambda Returned Payload Different Than Received Payload

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Lambda function that has been working as expected for months. It delivers a python dictionary using json.dumps

I added a new variable to the dictionary with a string 'true' or 'false' value. I store the dictionary into a variable, and log it one line before returning it using the same variable to the requester.

The logger shows the payload has 'variable_name': 'true' but when it gets delivered to the requested, it changes to 'false'.

What could cause the variable to change?

Comment: Also worth noting, API Gateway that it gets delivered through is not cached and I'm testing in incognito to avoid cached responses. I can see other changes that I've tested in the code get delivered correctly.

Comment: And changing true/false to 1/2 made no difference. This has to be happening on the Lambda side.

Comment: Changing true/false to 1/2 made no difference... *how?* 1 becomes 2 and 2 becomes 1?

Comment: Exactly. Inverse relationship remained. Despite the logs displaying a 1 being sent, the payload receives a 2.

Comment: That's quite bizarre... but it almost has to be something in your code -- perhaps an artifact if container reuse --since even it we assumed Lambda were somehow modifying your response, the Lambda infrastructure would not have a way to anticipate that the "opposite" of 1 is 2 (rather than, say, 0).  What we need is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behavior you observe.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to find some guidelines on how to provide something like that. This is very helpful!

Comment: I am SO sorry for the delayed response here. It turns out the website server was caching the results not the browser or the API Gateway. After flushing the web cache, everything operated correctly.

Comment: That does make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was website server caching as part of a Wordpress plugin. Clearing the website cache fixed the problem.